# Object is not an instance of declaring class exception

Tags: java, class, disk

I have a java class in my netbeans project that instantiate objects in the same time I added to that class with javassist api a new method and have loaded with custom class loader so that javassist has created the same class located in the disk, all the process is being at run-time.
I want to those old objects to invoke the new added methods by reflection.
I get "Object is not an instance of declaring class" exception

Please help me resolving this problem.

Serialization :

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
        SinglyLinkedList theList = new SinglyLinkedList();
          System.out.println("hello korat");

          theList.header=new Entry();
          theList.header.element=6;
          theList.header.next=new Entry();
          theList.header.next.element=6;
               theList.header.next.next=new Entry();
              theList.header.next.next.element=6;
              theList.size=2;


        File fichier = new File("SLL.xml");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fichier);
        try {
        xstream.toXML(theList, fos);
        } finally {
        fos.close();
```

Changing class with javassist by adding new method :

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        Loader cl = new Loader(pool);
        CtClass ctclass = pool.get("beans.SinglyLinkedList");
        ctclass.stopPruning(true);
        CtMethod newmethod = CtNewMethod.make("public void preF(int a){System.out.println(a);}",ctclass);
        ctclass.addMethod(newmethod);
        ctclass.writeFile();

        Class clazz = cl.loadClass("beans.SinglyLinkedList");
        Object nouvel =clazz.newInstance();
```

and then deserialization

```
xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("SLL.xml"));

        try {

            nouvel= xstream.fromXML(fis);

        System.out.println(nouvel.toString());
        clazz.cast(nouvel);

        } finally {

        fis.close();
        }
```

I want that the deserialized object invoke the new added method :

like : `preF.invoke(nouvel,10);`

but I get this exception : `Object is not an instance of declaring class`

Comment: Please provide some code, or a stack trace or an SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

The Method.invoke method will throw this exception if the method and the instance (as in `method.invoke(instance, args)`) are not in the same classloader.

For example, if you generate an object in your application and then pass it to a thread that has his own classloader and try to generate a method from that thread to invoke on your object, you will receive that exception.

In your case, you are saying that you loaded the class using a custom classloader so I suspect that you are not using that custom classloader to create the Method object.